# How significant is the Jedi's contribution to the Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-rebel-alliance

Looking only at the contributions of the surviving Jedi after Order 66, in what ways have they contributed to the Rebellion that would not have been possible without them?

Comment: I'm going to with the fact that Luke would not have gotten involved had it not been for Obi-Wan which saved the entire rebellion from the Death Star.

Comment: Ahsoka is seeming to be a larger player in establishing the Rebellion in new canon, however, she does not self identify as Jedi anymore

Comment: If Luke himself counts as a Jedi in Episode IV, blowing up the Death Star for starters. I know he wasn't technically a Jedi until episode VI but he relied on the force and Obi-Wan's limited training to land the shots in the tench run.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Even though Yoda said Luke was not a Jedi until **after he confronted Vader**, I would say his actions on Death Star 2 proved he was already worthy of the title, Jedi Knight. And that right up until Palpatine died, there was still technically a rebellion. Hmm... You can even say the rebellion existed after Palpatine's death because the Empire continued to exist for a short while.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Are you asking about Jedi other than Yoda, Kenobi, and Luke?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Remember, we're specifically looking at Jedi that were alive during and survived Order 66. Luke, unfortunately, doesn't fall into that category in and of himself.

Answer (score 8):

## Obi-Wan Kenobi and Yoda indirectly saved the whole galaxy from the Empire.

If it weren't for these two, pretty much nothing in Episode IV would have happened.  Luke Skywalker and Leia Organa likely would have been discovered and killed not long after birth, Han Solo would never have joined the Rebel cause, the Death Star would not have been destroyed, et cetera…

Later on, were it not for Yoda's training, Luke wouldn't have been able to stand a chance against Darth Vader and the Emperor (and likely wouldn't even have attempted to confront them).

So the actions of Obi-Wan and Yoda, by protecting, training, and guiding Luke, directly contributed to Luke's ability to save the galaxy from Vader, Palpatine, and the rest of the Empire.

Comment: I upvoted this, but I think the OP was asking about how Jedi other than Yoda and Kenobi contributed directly to the Rebel cause.

Comment: Well everything really. It'd be nice to include Yoda & Kenobi for completion's sake but logically this question  seeks to cover all bases beyond the obvious

Comment: @thegreatjedi At the risk of being "that guy," you should really put that into the body of your question if that's your intent. Yes, I agree that maybe it should be obvious (that was how I understood your question), but it's best to make that explicit if you want to get answers that exactly match your question. After all, this answer is an entirely valid response to your question as its phrased now, but it's not what you wanted...